# Updating layout product page, by placing div's into a new div - Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, product, layout, magento2.4

On our productpage we would like to place the two default div's `product.info.main` and `product.info.media` into a new div. How can we achieve this by updating the catalog_product_view.xml?

[image]

In this case we would like to place only the `product media` and `product-info-main` into a new div. So the `<div class="column main row">` element will only have 2 child elements.